# Pandas read_excel takes too long

Tags: python

I am sending the content of an xlsx file through a request to an azure function. There, I am doing the following:

```
bytes=request.get_body()
with io.BytesIO(bytes) as fh:
     df=pd.read_excel(fh,engine='openpyxl')
```

My problem is that the read_excel command takes too long, more than 20 minutes for a 85MB file. What I want to achieve is to convert the xlsx file that I get from the request to parquet and save it through another request to an Azure Storage Account.

Can this be done faster?

Comment: How big is the data inside the xlsx?

Comment: Have you tried Pandas API on Spark? Maybe you could use `pyspark.pandas.read_excel` as defined [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: The file has 85MB. There are 700000 rows and 16 columns

Comment: @TheSingularity I don't think pyspark it's an option. The code will be ran from an Azure Function